# Immediately update value inside textarea, taken from session after ajax send in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I wanted to retrieve value from session immediately after it updates, but for some reason, sometimes, the value that I get is still the old value, but some other time it gets the new value. Perhaps there is something missing in my code. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<?php

$temp_message = $this->session->userdata('temporary_message');

?>

<form action="<?php echo base_url($form_url)?>" method="post">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="receiver_number">Receiver:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="receiver_number" name="receiver_number" rows="5"><?php if (isset($temp_message)) { echo $temp_message['num_temp']; }?></textarea>
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('receiver_number');?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('message-text') != NULL) { echo 'has-error'; }?>">
            <label for="message_text">Message Text</label><div class="pull-right"><span id="chars">0</span></div>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message_text" id="message_text" rows="5"><?php if(isset($temp_message)) { echo $temp_message['message_temp']; }?></textarea>
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('message_text'); ?></span>
            <p id="message_temp" hidden><?php if(isset($temp_message)) { echo $temp_message['message_temp'];} ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

=================== JS ==================

```
$(window).on('unload, load, beforeunload', function () {
        let tempNum= $('#receiver_number').val();
        let messageTemp = $('#message_text').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('save-textarea'); ?>",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { 
                receiver_number: tempNum, 
                message_text : messageTemp
            }
        });
    });
```

================== Controller ==================

```
function save_textarea()
    {
        $data['num_temp'] = $_POST['receiver_number'];
        $data['message_temp'] = $_POST['message_text'];

        $message_session = $this->session->userdata('temporary_message');

        if (isset($message_session))
        {
            if (($message_session['num_temp'] != $data['num_temp']) || ($message_session['message_temp'] != $data['message_temp']))
            {
                $this->session->unset_userdata('temporary_message');
                $this->session->set_userdata('temporary_message', $data);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('temporary_message', $data);
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

So, I echoed out the value from the temporary_message session inside the `<textarea>`. As I said, sometimes the values in the `<textarea>` changed, sometimes it don't, therefore I have to insert the same value again, and reload the page, for several times (1, 2, sometimes 3 times). The values are being sent to the controller every time the user reload or change other page, then return to the same page again.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: you have to change the value of textarea in success method of ajax after returning from the controller, otherwise u have to reload to see the updated session value,

Comment: is your values are updating from other end as well ?

Comment: @KuldeepSingh yes, the values in the session are updated

Comment: it seems cache issue. Is it ?